# IOS - Mapkit crash - Is it a bug in xcode 4.2 and Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, crash, mkmapview, mapkit

I have found a very wierd problem in MKMapView that i think might be a bug in the new xcode 4.2 and ARC (Automatic Reference Count).

I created a very basic UIViewController class: MapViewController, that implements the protocol :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
```

I use a xib file to instantiate the mapview and link to its delegate i.e First Responder.

Nothing is added to the m file, except the autogenerated methods inherited by UIViewController.

The MapViewController is instantiated like:

```
MapViewController *mapView = [[MapViewController alloc]init];
[self.view addSubview:mapView.view];
```

So the program crash when the mapview is loaded and you scroll the map or zoom in/out. 
Main will crash with a EXE_BAD_ACCESS, meaning it is accessing illegal memory.

I Profiled it with instruments and checked for Zombies, and it turns out that the mapview overreleases an object and it crashes - as seen in the img.

[Zombie log http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2250562/xcode4.2-Mapview-Crash.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2250562/xcode4.2-Mapview-Crash.png)
![The Zombie log][1]

I do not think i do something wrong, so i would like to know if any of you might have a solution idea or want to test if you can reproduce the same result.
My next step would be to test in a new project without ARC to see if that changes the problem.

System info:
Xcode 4.2 Build 4D199 using ARC -> Automatic reference counting

App tested in Simulator for IOS 4.3

Answer (score 1):

Works flawlessly for me. Did you link the `MapKit.framework` to your target?

Comment: Framework was added and linked. I got it to work. I think i might have something to do with the adding of subview to the current view. I now use a NavigationController and push the mapview instead of adding subviews.